# In proving existence and uniqueness of ODE, why do we consider rectangular regions instead of circular regions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

I had this question while reading a proof on existence and uniqueness of solution for ODE...example: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf

In the proof, function $y' = F(x,y)$ is assumed to be continuous and defined over $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: |x-x_o|\leq r, |y-y_o|\leq r\}$

Since we are taking a segment from $x$, a segment from $y$, then their Cartesian product produces a square/rectangle in $\mathbb{R^2}$

But would the existence and uniqueness of solution ODE be violated if we had considered a circular region instead? In other words, does it matter if I exchanged my definition for $A$ above with 
$B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: |(x,y) - (x_o,y_o)| \leq r\}$

Comment: If it holds in $A$ it will hold in $B$, as soon as $B\subset A$.

Comment: @Chilango What you've written does not apply to this situation since the theorem is not a statement about elements of sets. Indeed, existence and uniqueness does not hold on domains which are not simply connected.

Comment: @AlexG: Obviously this is not a purely set theoretic issue.  Also obvious that $B$ being a ball is a simply-connected.  The point is both shapes generate the topology and that is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use circular regions instead. The validity of the existence and uniqueness theorem depends on the topology of the regions. I'm not sure what the most general sort of region is on which the theorem is valid. Certainly if the region is assumed to be [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space), as rectangles and disks are, then the theorem should hold.